# crawl https pages with crawler4j

Tags: java, ssl, https, crawler4j

For months now we used crawler4j to crawl a https site. Suddenly, since last friday, we're not  able to crawl the very same https site. Has something changed in the https-protocol?
The site is https://enot.publicprocurement.be/enot-war/home.do

As a test, just try to grab the title: Welkom op het platform e-Notification

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. To fix this we need a customized PageFetcher. You can find the sample here.
http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/issues/detail?id=174

Answer (score 1):

I found it works best when setting CrawlConfig

```
 CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
 config.setIncludeHttpsPages(true);
 config.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
 PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this PageFetcher subclass in place of your PageFetcher. This solved all the issues for me.

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;

import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlConfig;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.fetcher.PageFetcher;

public class PageFetcher2 extends PageFetcher {

public static final String DEFAULT_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0";
public static final RequestConfig DEFAULT_REQUEST_CONFIG = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000)
        .setSocketTimeout(60 * 1000).build();

public PageFetcher2(CrawlConfig config) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    super(config);

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(30);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(30);

    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
              .loadTrustMaterial(null, (certificate, authType) -> true).build();

    httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
              .setSSLContext(sslContext)
              .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
              .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
              .setUserAgent(DEFAULT_USER_AGENT)
              .setDefaultRequestConfig(DEFAULT_REQUEST_CONFIG)
              .build();
}

}
```